# Where can I find some examples of using Core Animation with Monotouch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-animation

I'm having little luck finding something useful to me via Googling.

Specifically what I'm looking for are some examples of 2D animation of sprites with monotouch and Core Animation, but anything at this point would provide insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin has a Core Animation sample in their [samples library](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/samples)

Comment: Huh, I'm embarrassed that I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: None of these samples seem to include sprite animation.